# Add a phone number and email to a contact in iOS with phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova

How can I add a phone number to a contact in iOS using cordova framework (phonegap)?
I've tried with an href:tel but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="tel:...">
```

Only adds a link to open the call window it does not save the number or email to device.

You need to add the specific code to insert of update the contact:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.create

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code:

```
var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
contact.displayName = "Plumber";
var name = new ContactName();
name.givenName = "Jane";
name.familyName = "Doe";
contact.name = name;

// phone numbers
var phoneNumbers = [];
phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('work', '212-555-1234', false);
phoneNumbers[1] = new ContactField('mobile', '917-555-5432', true);
phoneNumbers[2] = new ContactField('home', '203-555-7890', false);
contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;

// save
contact.save(onSaveSuccess,onSaveError);
```